# parse.com difference between clientKey and masterKey and, heck, all the other keys?

Tags: parse-platform

I've been reading the parse doco but haven't found a nice definition for each of the keys/ids it specifies on the overview page.

Can anybody give a nice definition of each, and a realistic example of when i'd need each item?

EDIT just to beat somebody to the punch, i *know* that the overview page defines each key. But the definitions are the kind of textbook example of "terrible"... they're not specific or clear enough for me. For example, *can* i use the application key from a windows application? Why not? I commmunicate with parse via json requests, it hardly knows nor can really care where i'm communicating from!

One tutorial I saw had me using the master key for all communications - i imagine this is a *terrible* idea if building a mobile app. etc  etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [answer](https://parse.com/questions/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-different-types-of-parse-application-keys) does not include the Windows key, but it does cover the difference between client, REST API and master keys.

Comment: it even covers the windows key now!